# Excel/VBA get full file path from file selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a VBA macro that does something like that

```
Sub test()

For Each X In Workbooks("file.xlsx").Sheets("sheetname")
    Do something
Next

End Sub
```

The sheet I am executing this macro from is **not** the sheet in the for-each loop. I also run this macro by a button in the sheet.

However, the filename and location will be different 99% of the time this macro is executed. So, I want a possibility when this macro is executed, that a "open file" dialog is appearing, where I select a file, and then that file is used in that macro.

<s>I'd also like to make it similar like this:</s>

```
Dim worksheetname as variable
For Each X in worksheetname.sheets("sheetname")
```

instead of making it directly in the line, as it is better than having it directly in the code.

However even with the hard coded filename I failed to do so properly (don't know what to dim it as, as well as how to set it to the file name then), if you guys could help me with that as well (in conjunction with making it via the file dialog), it would be great.

found out that one at least so far. so only getting it from a file dialog selection is left now

Thanks!

Xeb

Comment: That was an easy google question you could have done yourself man: [Application.FileDialog Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, I call it as a function with args for the file type filters and (optional) default directory that it will open:

```
Sub g()
    FilePath = FileSelectBox("*.xlsx")
    Msgbox "Filepath = " & FilePath
End Sub

Function FileSelectBox(ByRef FileType As String, Optional ByVal DefaultDir As String) As String
    Dim a As Object, FileName As String, varFile As Variant
    Set a = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With a
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select File..."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", FileType
        If Not IsMissing(DefaultDir) And DefaultDir <> "" Then .InitialFileName = DefaultDir
        If .Show = True Then
            For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
                FileSelectBox = varFile
            Next varFile
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

MSISDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196794.aspx

Comment: This gives me a "Type mismatch" error (I think it was error 13). The file dialog appears, as soon as I select the file, I get this error.

Comment: @xebtria apologies, try again now

Comment: now I get "subscript out of range" (again, after selecting the file)

Comment: @xebtria on which line?  Can you step through your code with f8?

Comment: it is in the "If .show = true then" line, then it opens the file dialog, I select the file, I click "open" (or double click), the file dialog closes and that error appears

Comment: actually, it is strange. this happens always the "first" time. when I then run it a second time directly afterwards, it actually works, it writes the filename in the variable, but then (the same error) appears in my sub in the line "For Each X in Workbooks(Workbookname).sheets("sheetname")"... then, the next time I run it, it again appears in the function in the "if .show = true" line.... very confusing...

Comment: I actually found the error. It had nothing to do with your code. I found out that for what I am doing in my sub requires only the filename. Your function however opens the file (which is exactly what it is supposed to do), which requires the full path. So I just needed to add another function that truncates the full path and leaves only the filename. Now it works without an error. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your function :)

Comment: @xebtria I'm confused, this function doesn't open the file selected at all, it will assign the file path that you select to the variable "FilePath" in the subroutine.  I've updated the code so it should be clear

Comment: sorry I mixed it up. I used your code to extract the filename with path (which it does), then used that result to open the file. there I got an error which the debugger for some reason showed to be inside your code, but it actually was in the code afterwards. so your code does exactly what I asked for, so thanks for that and sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @xebtria no worries- enjoy !